# Move <option> to top of list with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a button that will move the currently selected OPTION in a SELECT MULTIPLE list to the top of that list. I currently have [OptionTransfer.js](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/optiontransfer/combined_compact_source.html) implemented, which is allowing me to move items up and down the list.  I want to add a new function

```
function moveOptionTop(obj){ 
var i = obj.selectedIndex; 
if(i == 0){return;} 
var length = obj.options.length; 
for(j=length;j>0;j++){ obj.options[j] = obj.options[j-1]; //move all elements up a position to free up index 0 } 
obj.options[0] = obj.options[i+1]; //set new [0] element
for(j=i+1;j
```

Comment: uh, didn't you read the license notice?  Posting the code here is breaking the terms of that license.  Also - what is your question?

Comment: My question is how can move the currently selected option to the top of the list (i.e. set its index to 0). I made an attempt at the code, but it doesn't work and my algorithm seems terribly inefficient. I've re-edited my original question to include the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM manipulation methods. Given:

```
var select = document.getElementById ("...");     // select element
var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex] // option element
```

1. Remove selected option from select: `select.removeChild (option)`
2. Reinsert it as first child: `select.insertChild (option, select.firstChild)`

Or use select.add() and select.remove()

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

Comment: This is great info... but, I have a problem - it doesn't work with IE8. Here is the code, can you see any problem with it?

function moveOptionTop(el) { 
var selected = document.getElementById (el);     // select element
var option = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex]; // option element
selected.removeChild (option);
selected.add(option,selected.firstChild);
}