# Move selected option line to the last

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to force the selected option on a select tag to be on the last index when it is pressed or chosen. So far, the only pure Javascript solution that I saw is this one : [Move <option> to top of list with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788010/move-option-to-top-of-list-with-javascript)

Except that I tried changing it so that the chosen option goes to the very last.
It didn't work for me because it just deletes the chosen option line and does not create another one and place it on the last index.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!-- Created select tag so user can access history of talk -->
<div style="top:60px;position:absolute;z-index:2" id="speechBox">
    <!-- The select tag acts like a drop down button, so it passes its value to the input box and not to itself -->
    <select id = 'combo-box' title = "Saved Talk" onchange="goLast();document.getElementById('userText').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById('idValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  </select>
    <span class = "dropdown" name = "Saved Talk"></span>
    <input id ="userText" name="userText" type="text" onfocus="this.select()" ></input>
    <input name="idValue" id="idValue" type="hidden">
    <button id="speakText" class="toolbutton" title="Speak"></button>
  <hr>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
<script>
function goLast(){
    var select = document.getElementById("combo-box");
    var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    select.removeChild(option);
    select.insertChild(option, select.lastChild);
}

</script>
```

Help is appreciated. Javascript if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you removed the selected option and used the append method to insert it as the last child into the select:

```
var select = document.getElementById("combo-box");
var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
select.removeChild(option);
select.append(option);
```